# How to develop foxx services using arangodb web interface

Tags: arangodb, foxx

I am creating foxx services, right now I am doing it in VS Code and uploading the zip file in the services section with a mount point in DEVELOPMENT mode. Now I want to quick edit the foxx service in web interface itself. I was reading this possible but for some reason I do not get an option to edit it using web interface. Am I missing some configuration/setting or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do rapid development with Foxx is to use an IDE that automatically uploads modified files to a local 'deployment' location.

For example, if you use WebStorm IDE, and edit the files in a directory that is integrated with GIT, then you can checkout and check in your code.

WebStorm (or other IDE's as well) have a feature where they monitor edited files, and then automatically copy those files to a destination location.

You can set it up so that it notices when you save a file, then rather than zip it and deploy it via the web UI, it just copies the files to the directory that Foxx is using as the source of your web service.

If you have the Foxx service running in 'Development' mode, then it recompiles every invocation, so it will pick up the newly edited changes that just got copied in.

You need to find the target directory that you have your Foxx Service running out of, when you enable Development mode it will tell you the path in the Web UI.

Not sure if you can do that with VSCode, but if you can then that's the easiest way to do it.